# How to Rollback Insert/Update in spark (Scala) using JDBC

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql, mssql-jdbc

Is there a way to implement commit and rollback in spark when performing DML on RDBMS? I'm working on a task that involve inserting and updating records in Sql Server. I'm running sqoop command in Spark with JDBC.
I want to make provision for failure by implementing rollback feature so that in case the job fails mid way during the DML operation, I want to revert back to the previous stage where the RDBMS was. Can this be done in spark using Scala? I did lot of searches online and I was not able to come up with a solution. Any help or a pointer to where I can get relevant info will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ran into same issue. Implemented it using Scala/JDBC code.

Comment: Hi @morfious902002, would you mind sharing how you did it please?